# How would I convert this state-transition diagram into a regular expression ?

Tags: relations

The state-transition diagram of a finite-state recogniser is as follows :

[image]

Comment: What do the undirected edges mean?

Comment: @AlexR - I'm unsure. I'm working off a practice paper and this is as displayed on one of the questions. I would assume the edges are supposed to be directed on the path towards the acceptance state.

Comment: Okay, in that case my answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the undirected edges are meant left-to-right ($\to$).

Start with $s_0$ and repeat as many $a$ and $c$ as you want, then transition with $b$: `[ac]*b`. Then we need a $d$,$a$ and optionally any number of occurrences of $b$,$d$,$a$, i.e.
`[ac]*bda(bda)*`
Or shorter

```
[ac]*(bda)+
```